# ASP Classic to -- Webforms with no ViewState?

Tags: asp.net, asp-classic

This is an odd question, and it just occurred to me today. I've been trying to convert an ASP Classic application for a couple of years now into .NET Webforms, which I knew way back when.

The ASP Classic app in question is pretty much a CRUD app, but I've added over the years a lot of jQuery and Ajax, so it's pretty responsive and behaves the way I'd like, so it's not a fill form, post to page type of app. I'm still developing that one in parallel with the .NET one as new features are required.

In any case, the WebForms that I go back and look at is cluttered with ViewState and controls named weird and total crap.

I don't have a lot of time coming up - tight dev schedules - so I was thinking about using the WebForms without ViewState so I can essentially pull over the Ajax and jQuery code from the ASP pages and use .NET almost like ASP with the benefit being the debugging *and* the extensive libraries of data access and business logic components I've written in .NET for standalone console apps.

Again, tight schedule. I've got an isolated portion of the app in ASP.NET (Administrator Pages), so I could dump ViewState and be able to start reusing front-end code.

1. Is this an ok approach in transition? I'm not sure yet what my ultimate platform will be (MVC or WebForms)
2. Is there anything else I must do besides disable ViewState to make my code behave and for page elements to not do anything "funky" like rename controls or insert code?

Comment: I'm asking specifically about the feasibility of doing this as a short-term solution; I mention MVC in #1 in "i'm not sure what my future platform will be" but it's not possible now.

Comment: What about Asp.Net web page?. Since your application is written in classic ASP, it won't take much time to convert in asp.net webpage.